# Is there a way in UIPasteboard to create a custom DetectionPattern with regular expressions?

Tags: swift, uikit, uipasteboard

I'm trying to use the **`UIPasteboard.general.detectPatterns`** function to identify specific custom patterns. The documentation suggests that I can create my own `DetectionPattern`, but I'm having trouble finding out how to do that.

For example, to detect flight numbers, I can use the following code snippet:

```
            UIPasteboard.general.detectPatterns(for: [\.flightNumbers], completionHandler: { result in

                switch result {
                case .success(let detectedPatterns):
                    if detectedPatterns.contains(\.flightNumbers) {
                        print(UIPasteboard.general.string)
                    } else {
                        // We won't be retrieving the value, so we won't get a notification banner
                        break
                    }


                case .failure(_): break

                }
            })
```

I'd like to achieve a similar result using custom patterns defined with regular expressions.

I have tried to use:

```
UIPasteboard.DetectionPattern(rawValue: )
```

However, I did not succeed.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code:

`UIPasteboard`'s `detectPatterns` API doesn't natively support custom patterns based on regular expressions. The available detection patterns are predefined, and creating new patterns directly through `UIPasteboard.DetectionPattern` isn't supported.

However, if you need to identify custom patterns using regular expressions, you'd need to retrieve the content of the pasteboard and apply your regex detection logic on it. For instance:

```swift
let pasteboardContent = UIPasteboard.general.string
let regexPattern = "YOUR REGEX PATTERN HERE"
let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: regexPattern)

if let matches = regex?.matches(in: pasteboardContent ?? "", options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: pasteboardContent?.count ?? 0)), !matches.isEmpty {
    print("Pattern found!")
} else {
    print("Pattern not found.")
}
```

This code manually checks for the regex pattern within the UIPasteboard's string content.

Comment: Hi Trinity, thank you for your answer. However, I'd like to find a way to escape from reading the pasteboard string value, and read it if and only if it matches the regex pattern given by me.